# Catching panic! when Rust called from C FFI, without spawning threads

Tags: multithreading, error-handling, rust, ffi, stack-unwinding

I'm working on a [Rust wrapper for the Duktape JavaScript interpreter](https://github.com/emk/duktape-rs). In a normal use case, the call stack will look like this:

1. Rust: Arbitrary application code.
2. Rust: My library wrapper.
3. C: The Duktape interpreter.
4. Rust: My Rust code.
5. Rust: Arbitrary callbacks into application code.

What happens if (5) calls `panic!`? According to various Rust developers on IRC, attempting to `panic!` from inside non-Rust callframes like (3) may result in undefined behavior.

But according the Rust documentation, the only way to catch a `panic!` is using [`std::task::try`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/task/fn.try.html), which spawns an extra thread. There's also [`rustrt::unwind::try`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/rustrt/unwind/fn.try.html), which cannot be nested twice within a single thread, among other restrictions.

One solution, proposed by Benjamin Herr, is to abort the process if the code in (5) panics. I've packaged his solution as [`abort_on_panic`](https://github.com/emk/abort_on_panic-rs), and it appears to work, for values of "work" that include "crashing the entire program, but at least not corrupting things subtly":

```
abort_on_panic!("cannot panic inside this block", {
    panic!("something went wrong!");
});
```

But is a way to emulate `std::task::try` without the overhead of thread/task creation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Rust 1.9.0, you can use [`panic::catch_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) to recover the error:

```
use std::panic;

fn main() {
    let result = panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        panic!("oh no!");
    });
    assert!(result.is_err());
}
```

Passing it to the next layer is just as easy with [`panic::resume_unwind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.resume_unwind.html):

```
use std::panic;

fn main() {
    let result = panic::catch_unwind(|| {
        panic!("oh no!");
    });

    if let Err(e) = result {
        panic::resume_unwind(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Editor's note: This answer predates Rust 1.0 and is no longer necessarily accurate. Other answers still contain valuable information.

You cannot 'catch' a `panic!`. It terminates execution of the current thread. Therefore, without spinning up a new one to isolate, it's going to terminate the thread you're in.

Comment: Thank you! Is it actually necessary for `std::task::try` to actually spawn a new OS thread? It seems like it could be implemented to save some runtime state, invoke the "task" in the same OS thread, and restore the runtime state when it finishes. This would maintain the same public API as the current version, but it might save the cost of calling `pthread_new` everything JavaScript calls out to Rust.

Comment: That's a bit higher-level than Rust is.