# Is there any reason to put a semicolon after panic?

Tags: rust

Is there a difference between `panic!("blah");` and `panic("blah")`?

As I understand things, semicolons differentiate between statements and expressions<sup>[1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch03-03-how-functions-work.html#statements-and-expressions)</sup>. Put differently, the lack of a semicolon shows that a value is expected as a result of the expression<sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26665514/9614249)</sup>.

This is pretty straight forward in most cases, but `panic!` causes the current thread to terminate. The program will never return from `panic!` and so the result of the expression is meaningless, right?

Will the expression `panic!("blah")` ever behave differently than the statement `panic!("blah);`?

Comment: Because the lexer and syntactic analyser is built like that.

Comment: @KoltPenny what do you mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In 99% of the cases, there's no meaningful difference. I'd just let rustfmt do whatever it wants to do and not think about it.

> Is there any reason to put a semicolon after panic?

Yes. If you decide to stick a panic in the middle of some code for some quick-and-dirty debugging, if you don't add the semicolon you get a syntax error:

```
fn main() {
    // ... some code ...

    // We add a quick panic for some reason
    panic!("oops")

    // ... some code ...
    1;
}
```

```
error: expected one of `.`, `;`, `?`, `}`, or an operator, found `1`
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
5 |     panic!("oops")
  |                   - expected one of `.`, `;`, `?`, `}`, or an operator here
...
8 |     1;
  |     ^ unexpected token
```

With the semicolon, you will be able to compile with some warnings about unreachable code.

There's also the implicit question:

> Is there any reason to **not** put a semicolon after panic?

The one I can think of is when you are writing your own divergent function:

```
fn crash_override() -> ! {
    panic!("oops")
}
```

It's not needed, but it might appear more obvious to a reader that the never type is being "returned" from `panic!` in this case.

> Is there a difference between `panic!("blah");` and `panic("blah")`?

Yes, the former is a statement, the latter is an expression.

> but `panic!` causes the current thread to terminate.

That's the default behavior, yes, but it's not the only one. When `panic = abort` is not enabled, [you can catch panics if you need to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27384824/155423).

Comment: Thanks for the very comprehensive answer! Just for clarification, the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27423473/9614249) on the question you linked is now outdated and incorrect, right?

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic yeah. I just edited it to note that.