# Why is the semicolon after the return statement optional?

Tags: rust

I'd like to iterate over a list of `Option`s. If there's a value in one of them, I want to return an error. Here's a contrived example:

```rust
fn test(options: &[Option<u8>]) -> Result<(), &u8> {
    for option in options {
        match option {
            None => (),
            Some(value) => {
                // do some stuff here, so I can't just go
                // Some(value) => return Err(value),
                return Err(value); // this semicolon is optional
            }
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Adding another semicolon results in an error, but deleting the semicolon does not.

Why is the semicolon after the return statement optional?

Which form should be used in idiomatic Rust: semicolon or no semicolon? Both are accepted by the compiler and seem to produce the same result.

Comment: FWIW — `if let Some(value) = options.iter().flatten().next() { return Err(value); }`

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [What's the difference between using the return statement and omitting the semicolon in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59013389/155423); [Are semicolons optional in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26665471/155423); [Why is using return as the last statement in a function considered bad style?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27961879/155423); [Is there any reason to put a semicolon after panic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50610000/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between using the return statement and omitting the semicolon in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013389/whats-the-difference-between-using-the-return-statement-and-omitting-the-semico)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why is the semicolon after the return statement optional?

The crux of the issue is that `return` is not a statement (by itself) in Rust, it's an **expression** returning `!`<sup>1</sup>.

This means that the idiomatic formatting of your test case is actually:

```rust
fn test(options: &[Option<u8>]) -> Result<(), &u8> {
    for option in options {
        match option {
            None => (),
            Some(value) => return Err(value),
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Note that I removed the `{}` around the `return` expression. The right-hand side of `=>` takes an expression, `return Err(value)` is an expression, it fits right in, no extra fluff needed.

<sup>1</sup> *`!` denotes the bottom type in programming language theory, a type with no instance, and is used to signal expressions which diverge. It's also known as the NEVER type.*

---

As explained in [Are semicolons optional in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665471/are-semicolons-optional-in-rust) expressions can be turned into statements in Rust by adding a `;`.

Since the right-hand side of `=>` requires an expression, you cannot directly use `return Err(value);` (since that's now a statement) but you can use a *block expression* which happens to contain statements, and possibly a final expression.

The optional `;` is therefore a property of the *block*:

- A block containing a single statement, no final expression: `{ return Err(value); }`. Its type is `()`.
- A block containing just a final expression: `{ return Err(value) }`. Its type is `!`.

Comment: What if I want to do some stuff before the return so I can't use Some(value) => return value, ? What would be the idiomatic form in that case? I updated my question.

Comment: @RichApodaca: In that case you'll need a block, and then just run `cargo fmt`. Idiomatic syntax is accepted to be the default of `cargo fmt`. In practice, though, both work and produce the same result, so does it really matter?

Answer (score 5):

The `;` can be omitted here because `return` is an expression that evaluates to the [`!` type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.never.html), which is then coerced to the empty tuple `()`, so all match arms have the same type.

> which form should be used in idiomatic Rust?

It's idiomatic to add the `;` or to remove the surrounding curly braces. That's also what `cargo fmt` does.

Comment: Also, block statements (such as the `for ... { ... }` loop) implicitly have a semicolon after them, so in a sense there *is* a semicolon -- an invisible one.

Comment: Yes, after the `for` loop, but not after the `return` statement.